# Trying to get ActionBar working in a phonegap application

Tags: cordova, android-actionbar, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to build a phonegap application with actionbar. my project activity extends CordovaActivity and i am using the following code...

```
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Home"));
    bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Something"));
```

the ActionBar's object is returning null. Any help regarding this code or any plugin or anything relevant to adding action in phonegap will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check your manifest to see if the style is set correctly. if it's set to "something.NoTitleBar" then remove the theme style and it should be working.

Answer (score 0):

A year later I had the same problem. I resolved it by doing these two things:

1. I completely removed the `android:theme` entry in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. Removing `.NoTitleBar` was not enough for my app.
2. Add this to the Cordova `config.xml` (I added it to the `<platform name="android">` section):

   `<preference name="ShowTitle" value="true"/>`

This setting defaults to `false`. And if `false`, the title bar is unavailable.

Using this [link about Android configuration](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_android_config.md.html), you can see the above android option.

And if you care, here is the relevant piece of Cordova code which does not seem to turn on the title bar, only turn it off:

```
if (!preferences.getBoolean("ShowTitle", false))
{
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
}
```

I hope it helps someone else.

Comment: helmbert edited out the most important part that needs to be added to the config.xml file: '<preference name="ShowTitle" value="true"/>'

Comment: I've suggested an edit that should fix that issue.  It was an accidental by-product of his edit.  The code was left in the post but the renderer assumed it to be actual html when following list items, rather than formatted code to display.